# How to count the same date values per day

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, count

I'm completly begginer but and  don't even know what type this query is.

BTW. I want to get `count Date(MYdatetime)` type values `per day` by join the same table.

Is there any question comparing this query?

I have query like that:

```
select 
    date_format(
        adddate('2011-1-1', @num:=@num+1), 
        '%Y-%m-%d'
    ) date
from 
    any_table,    
    (select @num:=-1) num
limit 
    365
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for here. Perhaps you could provide an example of the input data and expected output

Comment: You can edit your question above and use markdown to format code and data. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I have a table, for example march which  have saved records in only twenty days, but i Want to show days which are not  (rest of march days. This days are  not on the table).

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    year(theDate), 
    month(theDate), 
    day(theDate), 
    count(*) 
FROM 
   test_table 
GROUP BY 
    year(theDate), 
    month(theDate), 
    day(theDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, I would simply do:

```
select date(t.datecol), count(*)
from any_table t
group by date(t.datecol);
```

If you want data for a particular time span, use a `where` clause:

```
select date(t.datecol), count(*)
from any_table t
where t.datecol >= '2011-01-01' and t.datecol < '2012-01-01'
group by date(t.datecol);
```

Comment: but steel have not days which are not on the table.

Comment: Days which are not on the table would be 0. It's significantly easier to not worry about those than it is to create the utility join table for filling in those gaps with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting a count of all dates in a given time frame, including those dates that are not in the table (and thus would have a count of 0). This is a bit of a headache but not unprecedented. You basically need to create a utility table that is just every date you could possibly want and then do an outer join against that table. So create a simple table like:

```
CREATE TABLE `all_dates` (
  `the_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And populate it with all dates you think you could potentially need. I think a 10 year radius from the current year would be good. So fill it with every date between 2008-01-01 and 2028-12-31.

```
INSERT INTO all_dates
(the_date) VALUES
('2008-01-01'),
('2008-01-02'),
('2008-01-03')
```

There is probably a clever way to generate all rows in one query using a procedure or somesuch, but I don't know what it would be, so I would personally just create a simple script (like in PHP) to generate those rows.

Once the `all_dates` table has all the date value rows for your needs, you can then do a query to get the count of each date (including missing dates) like:

```
SELECT DATE(all_dates.the_date), COUNT(any_table.datecol)
FROM any_table
RIGHT JOIN all_dates ON DATE(any_table.datecol) = all_dates.the_date
GROUP BY all_dates.the_date
HAVING all_dates.the_date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2012-01-01'
```

Comment: Yes, this is exaclty this wat I mean. Thanks so mych for that. But as you said I dont want to create brand new  table all_dates.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. An all_dates table is cheap. It's a little cheesy, but it's what you need to achieve your goal. Believe me, I ran into this same dillema 10 years ago, and that was the solution then and now.